# Scrolling with a listview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, vertical-scrolling

I'm having issues with Flutter wherein a screen I have created will only scroll if the user touches the padding surrounding a listview comprised of cards, and not if the actual list is interacted with itself.

The Widget tree looks similar to as below:

```
child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 500.0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'List',                       
                     ),
                    Container(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: list.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(                            
                              child: ListTile(
```

How would I go about making the screen scrollable regardless of where on the screen the user touches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` in Listview

```
ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have solved exactly what I was looking to achieve!